# Wrong document if script dynamically inserted into iframe head

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-analytics, domdocument

On iframe load, I insert google analytics snippet into iframe document HEAD.

Then the snippet is inserting this script

```
<script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
```

in the parent document HEAD, I expected it to be inserted in the iframe document HEAD...

---

Google snippet is executed in the iframe document, so why is it inserting script tage in **parent window document** ??

You can easily reproduce using this and run index.html

**no_analytics.html** contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>body{color: #AAA;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>no analytics</body>
</html>
```

**index.html** contains:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="insert" src="no_analytics.html"></iframe>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('insert').onload= function() {
                var c =
                    "(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){"+
                    "(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),"+
                    "m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)"+
                    "})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');";

                $('#insert').contents().find('head').append($('<script>').html(c));
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please note that this is not happening if the iframe contains already the google analytics snippet.

Comment: Please let me know if something is not clear in my explanation. This is so odd, I am really curious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is because, your **jquery** code is passing parent document object as context to Your  google analytics snippet, so when Your  **google analytics snippet code** is invoked **function retrieve as parameter parent document object**, you can check this behaviour using this example, You can see in dev tools in chrome on which document is pointing Your google script.

**no_analytics.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>body{color: #AAA;}</style>
    <script>
        console.log("document => ", document);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>no analytics</body>
</html>
```

and **index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="insert" src="no_analytics.html"></iframe>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('insert').onload= function() {
            var c =
                "(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){

                  console.log('document from google script => ', s);

                 i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){"+
                "(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),"+
                "m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)"+
                "})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');";

            $('#insert').contents().find('head').append($('<script>').html(c));
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

To make Your example **work** I use javascript code without jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="insert" src="no_analytics.html"></iframe>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('insert').onload = function () {
            var c =
                "(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){ console.log('document from google script => ', s);i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){" +
                "(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o)," +
                "m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)" +
                "})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');",
            documentIframe = document.getElementById('insert').contentDocument;

            var script = documentIframe.createElement('script');
            script.innerHTML = c;

            documentIframe.head.appendChild(script);
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

And here is the result of the above script

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var c =
        "(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){" +
        "(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o)," +
        "m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)" +
        "})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');";
    $('#insert').contents().find('head').append($('<script>').html(c));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, but I just tried and <script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script> is still inserted in parent document HEAD.